# Linear Equivalence between points on a compactified $y^2=x^3+1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, smooth-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm following through Geometry of Algebraic Curves at the moment. I am asked to compactify $y^2=x^3+1$, which becomes the curve $C$ defined by $Y^2Z=X^3+Z^3$ with the additional point at infinity $[0:1:0]$, in projective coordinates. I am now asked to show the linear equivalence between the divisors

$2(-1,0)\sim 2(-w,0)$, where $w^3=1$ is any 3-rd root of unity.

In other words, I have to find a meromorphic function $f$ on $C$ such that $f$ has multiplicity $2$ at precisely $(-1,0)$ and $(-w,0)$. I don't even know where to begin for this. Any tips or references would be welcome.

Comment: The answer below is good. For the more general idea note that $(-1,0)$ and $(-w, 0)$ are $2$-torsion points on $C$ (as an elliptic curve) and follow the proof of Prop III.3.4 in Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f:=\dfrac{(x+z)^2}{(x+wz)^2}=\dfrac{x^2+2xz+z^2}{x^2+2wxz+w^2z^2}$.

We simply have to observe that $f\neq 0$ as element in $k(C)$.

Enough to consider over the open set $z=1$. That is to see $\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{(x+w)^2}=\dfrac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+2wx+w^2}$ is non-zero.

If not, then there is a polynomial $g$ such that $g(x^2+2x+1)=0$ in $k[C]=\dfrac{k[x, y]}{(y^2-x^3-1)}$.

That is $g(x^2+2x+1)=h(y^2-x^3-1)$ in $k[x,y]$.

Now $g(x, 0)(x^2+2x+1)=h(x, 0)(-x^3-1)$.

So by UFD ness of $k[x]$, $g(x, 0)| h(x, 0)$ and $h(x, 0)| g(x, 0)$.

But $\deg g(x, 0)+1=\deg h(x, 0)$,  a contradiction. Hence $f\neq 0$.

Now more to the point: $$div(f)=2(-1, 0, 1)-2(-w, 0, 1)$$

which gives the desired linear equivalence.

Comment: Sorry but why wouldn't (−1,y,1) also have nonzero multiplicity in the divisor, for y≠0?

Comment: Answering my own question, (-1,y,1) does not lie on the curve.

Comment: I don't think your computation of $\operatorname{div}(f)$ is correct---I get $4(-1: 0: 1) - 4(-\omega: 0: 1)$. The map $x$ is already ramified at each of the $2$-torsion points with index $2$, so you shouldn't have to square the numerator and denominator. For instance $\operatorname{div}(x+z) = 2(-1:0:1) - 2(0:1:0)$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn can you expand upon this a bit? Why is the map x already ramified there?

Comment: @JonDoe $x$ is generically a $2$-to-$1$ map, since for a given $x_0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$, there are usually two solutions for $y$ to the equation $y^2 = x_0^3 + 1$. However, when $x_0$ is a root of $x^3 + 1$, in which case the equation is just $y^2 = 0$, there is only one solution, and consequently there is only one point, $(x_0, 0)$, above $x_0$.